# Group columns of dataframe on conditions

Tags: python, pandas

```
id    cid    cc
j1    1      1
j1    1      2
j1    1      3
j2    1      1
j2    1      4
j3    1      5
j3    1      8
j4    1      1
j4    1      6
```

here for the same cid I want to join 3(fixed) different id's as one R1 in other column rid.take the first j value, and get all other j's in which the cc's are available. For R1 I should get j1,j2 and j3 as R1 bcoz of some cc values are common in j1,j2 & j3 and j3 should be in R2.I want to return the last value in j3(8 in my case)

My final output should look like:

```
id    cid    cc    rid
j1    1      1     R1
j1    1      2     R1
j1    1      3     R1
j2    1      1     R1
j2    1      4     R1
j3    1      5     R2
j3    1      8     R2
j4    1      1     R1
j4    1      6     R1
```

I am new to python so please help me.